# Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5150,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I was trying to add a reference de.softpro.doc.winmd into a blank UWP application, then try to build the project but failed with error as titled.
Screen shot for your reference:[image: Error details]

Not sure it's a Visual Studio issue or not? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current version is 17.6.5.

Comment: It looks above sdk does not support UWP platfrom?

Comment: It should support UWP.

Comment: Any document can you share, I will test it.

Comment: I share a sample project in the github: https://github.com/supperwu/SignDoc

Comment: Document for your reference: https://docshield.kofax.com/SD/en_US/3.3.0-t85kv64y7c/help/SDK_dotNetnoex/signdocsdk_winrt_comp.html

Comment: You project miss `Repeat for SignatureContainer.dll and EncoderDecoder.dll`

Comment: No need these two dlls just for build the sample project

Comment: I followed above toturial with a blank app, it looks well without exception, can try this [demo](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SinDoc)

Comment: I can't access this repository, it's private？

Comment: I compared your demo with mine, I have removed the de.softpro.doc.pri file, I can build without exception. Thanks for your time.

Comment: cool, do you means pri file cause this problem ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I didn't include pri file into project just put it into the folder, after removing the pri file no exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [document](https://docshield.kofax.com/SD/en_US/3.3.0-t85kv64y7c/help/SDK_dotNetnoex/signdocsdk_winrt_comp.html) and add related dll and winmd file to the project exclude pri file from project just put it into the folder, the project will not throw exception.
And I have made code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SinDoc) for people who view this samilar problem later.